# Ubuntu - wlan0 and tun0 interfaces mutual exclusion

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

When `openvpn` is started `tun0` interface is created and right away `wlan0` is deleted.

How to prevent this from happening?

EDIT: I noticed that the same issue appears also for other
VPN type, so this is not OpenVPN specific.
I used VmWare's SSL VPN, with the same issue happening.

I looked at similar cases, there were issues with roaming that looked similar: [OpenVPN causes WLAN/WiFi to disconnect in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/563797/openvpn-causes-wlan-wifi-to-disconnect-in-linux)

However, the same fix would not work for me.
Looks like on `Ubuntu 16` `wpa_supplicant` is configured in different (mysterious for me )

Likely that the root cause is the same (roaming), but I don't know how to configure interface startup scripts so that tun0 creation would not
trigger wlan0 deletion

When there is `eth0` in use, `vpn tunnel` works without problems.
I also have no problems with `wlan` when `openvpn` is off.

Appreciating hints on how to debug `wlan_supplicant`.

System info:

- Linux ul001541 4.4.0-62-generic
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

I can reproduce the issue by running openvpn:

```
>openvpn slviovyos.ovpn
```

Here is the config file slviovyos.ovpn:

```
client
proto tcp
remote-cert-tls server
verb 2
dev tun0
cert tecodevteam.crt
key tecodevteam.key
ca ca.crt
remote 169.50.156.11 3389
```

Logs, appearing when wlan0 is up and running, and openvpn got started:

```
>journalctl -xe
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8119] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1486987120.812:38): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0/type" pid=1570 co
mm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 audit[1570]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0/type" pid=1570 comm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denie
d_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8191] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8191] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: A new network interface has been detected.
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8194] device (tun0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed') [10 20 41]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: 10.33.79.122 10
.34.96.46 10.255.254.4 FE80:0:0:0:B9D9:E3E:F65B:4C83 FE80:0:0:0:4EEB:42FF:FEEF:FD0D
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7695 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical 
MAC addresses
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8204] keyfile: add connection in-memory (a745dd9a-c4f0-4337-9267-8e8c5f6cd9e9,"tun0")
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8209] device (tun0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed') [20 30 41]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8218] device (tun0): Activation: starting connection 'tun0' (a745dd9a-c4f0-4337-9267-8e8c5f6cd9e9)
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8298] device (tun0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none') [30 40 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8305] device (tun0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none') [40 50 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8311] device (tun0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none') [50 70 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1486987120.828:39): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0/type" pid=1570 co
mm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 audit[1570]: AVC apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/sssd" name="/sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0/type" pid=1570 comm="sssd" requested_mask="r" denie
d_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8327] device (tun0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none') [70 80 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8336] device (tun0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none') [80 90 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8339] device (tun0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none') [90 100 0]
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987120.8413] device (tun0): Activation: successful, device activated.
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 dbus[1331]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 dbus[1331]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 nm-dispatcher[6799]: req:1 'up' [tun0]: new request (2 scripts)
feb 13 13:58:40 ul001541 nm-dispatcher[6799]: req:1 'up' [tun0]: start running ordered scripts...
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 systemd[1]: Reloading OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has begun reloading its configuration
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has begun reloading its configuration
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 sshd[2089]: Received SIGHUP; restarting.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 systemd[1]: Reloaded OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has finished reloading its configuration
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has finished reloading its configuration
here
--                                                                                                                                                                                   [20/1774]
-- The result is done.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 sshd[2089]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 sshd[2089]: Server listening on :: port 22.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 ntpd[2172]: Listen normally on 10 tun0 10.255.254.4:123
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 ntpd[2172]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: wlan0: deauthenticating from a0:d3:c1:a8:e0:60 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=a0:d3:c1:a8:e0:60 reason=3 locally_generated=1
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::4eeb:42ff:feef:fd0d.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 dhclient[4249]: receive_packet failed on wlan0: Network is down
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.5755] WiFi hardware radio set disabled
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 10.34.96.46.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.5755] device (wlan0): state change: activated -> unavailable (reason 'none') [100 20 0]
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::4eeb:42ff:feef:fd0d on wlan0.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 avahi-daemon[1805]: Withdrawing address record for 10.34.96.46 on wlan0.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: rfkill: WLAN soft blocked
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 kernel: cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: rfkill: WLAN soft blocked
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-rfkill.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-rfkill.service has begun starting up.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: A network interface has gone down.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: Function: logInterfaces File: ../../vpn/AgentUtilities/Routing/InterfaceRouteMonitorCommon.cpp Line: 477 IP Address Interface List: 10.33.79.122 10
.255.254.4 FE80:0:0:0:B9D9:E3E:F65B:4C83
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 acvpnagent[2236]: Function: netInterfaceNoticeCategoryHandler File: ../../vpn/Agent/MainThread.cpp Line: 7695 Network Interface change detected, refreshing physical 
MAC addresses
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 systemd[1]: Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-rfkill.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-rfkill.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.6082] dhcp4 (wlan0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 4249
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.6082] dhcp4 (wlan0): state changed bound -> done
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.6107] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 dnsmasq[1705]: setting upstream servers from DBus
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 dnsmasq[1705]: using nameserver 10.34.8.112#53
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 dnsmasq[1705]: using nameserver 131.207.136.44#53
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 dnsmasq[1705]: using nameserver 10.42.81.48#53
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.6272] audit: op="radio-control" arg="wireless-enabled:0" pid=6930 uid=0 result="success"
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 NetworkManager[1410]: <info>  [1486987122.6274] manager: WiFi now disabled by radio killswitch
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 nm-dispatcher[6799]: req:2 'down' [wlan0]: new request (2 scripts)
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 nm-dispatcher[6799]: req:2 'down' [wlan0]: start running ordered scripts...
feb 13 13:58:42 ul001541 wpa_supplicant[1627]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
feb 13 13:58:44 ul001541 ntpd[2172]: Deleting interface #8 wlan0, 10.34.96.46#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=66 secs
feb 13 13:58:44 ul001541 ntpd[2172]: Deleting interface #9 wlan0, fe80::4eeb:42ff:feef:fd0d%3#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=66 secs
```

Comment: Um, "OpenVPN"? Your logs don't mention OpenVPN at all – the only thing they have is Cisco AnyConnect. And on that note, have you tried using `openconnect` instead? In my experience it works a bit better than Cisco's proprietary client.

Comment: This is not about AnyConnect and openconnect (though I have all of them on the system). The anyconnect daeamon is not creating any vpn connections at the time of logging the issue, though the daemon is up, and some log entries can be seen in the journal. The issue appears once I start openvpn. I'll ad some info to the original question.